# How to build renamed POM xml

Tags: maven-2

I am relatively new to Maven. I actually wanted to know how to build the renamed pom.xml i.e.

there is a XML file with the name `parent-pom.xml`. Shall I directly name it to pom.xml and try building it or is there some other way to do it?

Answer (score 20):

Maven looks for the `pom.xml` file, so you should rename it that for it to work.

You could use another file name using the `-f` option.

`mvn -f parent-pom.xml`.